# How to update or create at same time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had one page that showed data from two tables with a left join and an edit button in front of every column. When the user clicks on the edit button, it goes to a different page where the user can update input fields, but at the same time, I want if some field is not showing data, we can create data only when both the id of tables match. By this, I can easily update it, but I can't create it shows an error

> Attempt to assign property "SchemeId" on null

**Controller**

```
public function SchConfigrationUpdate(Request $request, $SchemeId)
{
    $scheme = tbl_schemeconfigration::find($SchemeId);        
    $scheme->SchemeId = $request->input('SchemeId');       
    $scheme->MerchantCode = $request->input('MerchantCode');
    $scheme->BankAccountNumber = $request->input('BankAccountNumber');
    $scheme->BankAccountIFSC = $request->input('BankAccountIFSC');
    $scheme->save();        
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('success', 'Scheme Update Successfully');
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ url('SchConfigration-update/' . $user->SchemeId) }}" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <input type="hidden" name="SchemeId" value="{{ $user->SchemeId }}">
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_item">
            <label>Scheme Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="SchemeId" name="SchemeId"
                   placeholder="Enter scheme name" class="form-control" required
                   value="{{ $user->SchemeId }}">
            {{-- value="{{ request()->SchemeId }}" --}}
            {{-- if we want to pass scheme name just pass $user->SchemeName --}}
        </div>
        <div class="form_item">
            <label>Merchant Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="MerchantCode" name="MerchantCode"
                   placeholder="Enter Merchant Code" class="form-control" required
                   value="{{ $user->MerchantCode }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_item">
            <label>Bank Account Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="BankAccountNumber" name="BankAccountNumber"
                   placeholder="Bank account Number" maxlength="17" class="form-control" required
                   value="{{ $user->BankAccountNumber }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form_item">
            <label>Bank Account IFSC</label>
            <input type="text" id="BankAccountIFSC" name="BankAccountIFSC"
                   placeholder="Bank account IFSC" maxlength="11" class="form-control" required
                   value="{{ $user->BankAccountIFSC }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_row">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="primary_btn">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('SchConfigration') }}"
           role="button">Back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: laravel 8 sir @dbf

Comment: There is something called [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) in a thing called documentation

Comment: updateOrCreate not working for me sir please can you edit my controller for me @dbf

Comment: No no, you have to at least give it a try ..

Comment: sir i try once but error says " Attempt to assign property "SchemeId" on null " @dbf

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function SchConfigrationUpdate(Request $request, $SchemeId)
{
      $scheme = tbl_schemeconfigration::updateOrCreate(
          ['SchemeId' => $request->input('SchemeId')],
          [
              'MerchantCode' => $request->input('MerchantCode'),
              'BankAccountNumber' => $request->input('BankAccountNumber'),
              'BankAccountIFSC' => $request->input('BankAccountIFSC')
            ]
        );

      return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('success', 'Scheme Update Successfully');
}
```

Comment: sir one question why you put SchemeId in different bind like this  ['SchemeId' => $request->input('SchemeId')],

Comment: and one more question that why is error occur " Attempt to assign property "SchemeId" on null "   I want to know for future